# tomcat7@ubuntu: myHost:8080 is not working

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat7

I'm using tomcat7 on ubuntu server.

Even though I'm starting the tomcat7 my ip:8080 is not working [ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT]. I found a possible solution [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/390840/how-does-one-get-tomcat-to-bind-to-ipv4-address) but even changed from ipv6 to ipv4 the problem still exists.

Here is the result of `netstat -na | grep -e 8080`

```
root@ehr-se:/etc/init.d# netstat -na | grep -e 8080
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          127.0.0.1:37731         TIME_WAIT
```

This is my `catalina.out` output. There is no error...

```
Jun 26, 2015 2:29:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 26, 2015 2:29:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 788 ms
Jun 26, 2015 2:29:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 26, 2015 2:29:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
Jun 26, 2015 2:29:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
Jun 26, 2015 2:29:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml
Jun 26, 2015 2:29:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/EHR_SE.war
Jun 26, 2015 2:29:36 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/EHR_SE/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jun 26, 2015 2:29:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 26, 2015 2:29:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3319 ms
```

This is `catalina.out` while setting `address="0.0.0.0"` to `connector` in `server.xml`.

```
Jun 26, 2015 2:59:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080"]
Jun 26, 2015 2:59:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 912 ms
Jun 26, 2015 2:59:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 26, 2015 2:59:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
Jun 26, 2015 2:59:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
Jun 26, 2015 3:00:35 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [35,369] milliseconds.
Jun 26, 2015 3:00:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml
Jun 26, 2015 3:00:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/EHR_SE.war
Jun 26, 2015 3:00:35 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/EHR_SE/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jun 26, 2015 3:00:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080"]
Jun 26, 2015 3:00:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 38384 ms
```

I'll appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

The port 8080 was closed!